# Issues styling a chat room in meteor

Tags: html, css, meteor

I am trying to create a really simple chat room with meteor and I am not sure how to get the chat box to stay above the footer and overflow with a scroll bar.

This is using Bootstrap 3 as well.

Here is the template :

```
<div class="chat-body">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header">

            <h1>Chat room</h1>

        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">

        {{#each messages}}

            <li class="chat-message">

                <span class="chat-name h3"> {{name}} </span> : {{text}}

            </li>

        {{/each}}

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

<footer class="footer">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="input-group">

       <input type="text" class="form-control">

       <span class="input-group-btn">

       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">SendMessage</button>

       </span>

    </div>

  </div>

</footer>

</template>
```

And this is the CSS for the footer:

```
.chat-body {
}
.footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.chat-message {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.chat-name {
}
```

The Messages is just placeholder data. My question is how I should structure this so that the chat box will fill up the available page above the footer and overflow messages with a scroll bar.

The footer sits at the bottom of the screen but the messages just go below it as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your footer inside the "container" div.   Set position: relative; on the container div, and padding-bottom: 60px;   Then your existing css for the footer should push it into the 60px of bottom padding for the container div, keeping it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: With that the footer sits below the chat but I want the chat list to not go past the height of the window and turn into a scrollable section. Right now if there is many messages  you have to scroll the entire window down instead of having it all visible in the one window view.

Comment: Add overflow: scroll; to the div containing your chat.